# Why can't I use Powershell to create a network directory?

Tags: networking, powershell, path

I encounter a problem about using Powershell to create a network directory, the NT server's name is \ldnesd, in this server , I create a powershell script like this:

```
New-Item -Path "\\ldnesd\IndiaOption\MyDirectory" -type directory
```

the folder "IndiaOption" is shared and has all permission, but when running the script, it throws me the exception:Access to 'MyDirectory' is denied.
I've searched google but got no result, I am confused now, would you pls help? thx.
I am just wondering if powershell supports creating network path directory.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you have permissions to the IndiaOption share with your user credentials? Make sure you edit the share level permissions e.g Change, Full AND the NTFS permissions e.g Modify, Full. Try creating the directory at that path using Windows Explorer. Does it work?

Comment: Hi Andy, I can create the folder through Windows Explorer, but cann't create it using this little script, I have given the folder all the permission, it's really strange... thx for your reply.

Comment: Are you able to create it from cmd.exe - md \\ldnesd\IndiaOption\MyDirectory

Comment: I cann't , it throws me "Access is denied"

Comment: Well then, it doesn't seem like it's got anything to do with powershell then, right?

Comment: Have you tried creating this directory using an elevated (run as admin) powershell?

Comment: Hi x0n and jon Z, I have solved the problem, because that I didn't setup the share permission for everyone, so I cann't create the folder.thx for your reply. :)